# Change default sort order for Github

Tags: github, github-issues

Is there a way to change the default sort order in Github for issues and pull requests?  The default is "Newest", but I would prefer "Recently updated", as I want to see the most recent activity.

The default sort order often buries recent updates down far from the top of the list.  Every time I visit the list of issues or pull requests, I have to manually change the sort order to "Recently updated", which is annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub does not support this natively, however, there is an extension [Refined GitHub](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github) that includes [that](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#:%7E:text=Changes%20the%20default%20sort%20order%20of%20conversations%20to%20Recently%20updated.) as one of the many tweaks.

#### Refined GitHub

[Refined GitHub](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github) is a browser extension that simplifies the GitHub and GitHub Enterprise interfaces and adds useful features.

Most features can be disabled if they are JavaScript-based and the extension's CSS can be overridden in the extension's options.

The extension adds ~20 features for [conversations](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#conversations) including changing the [default sort order to Recently updated](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#:%7E:text=Changes%20the%20default%20sort%20order%20of%20conversations%20to%20Recently%20updated.).

The ~300 Features are listed on the [Repository page](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github) grouped by:

- [Repositories](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#repositories)
- [File management](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#file-management)
- [Code](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#code)
- [Writing comments](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#writing-comments)
- [Reading comments](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#reading-comments)
- [Conversations](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#conversations)
- [Viewing pull requests](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#viewing-pull-requests)
- [Editing pull requests](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#editing-pull-requests)
- [Commits](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#commits)
- [Tags and releases](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#tags-and-releases)
- [Profiles](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#profiles)
- [Newsfeed](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#newsfeed)
- [Notifications](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#notifications)
- [Global](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#global)
- [Netiquette](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#netiquette)
- [Fixes for GitHub shortcomings](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github#fixes-for-github-shortcomings)

The extension works with [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/refined-github/hlepfoohegkhhmjieoechaddaejaokhf) (and other Chromium browsers), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/refined-github-/) (including Firefox Android), and [Safari](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1519867270) on Mac, iOS, and iPadOS.